# Facebook API login button without using FB.Login() (i.e. no pop-up)

Tags: facebook

I'm creating a Facebook App and wanted to avoid firing off the Allow box, but it looks like I'm going to have to do that.

One option could be to call FB.Login(), but that generates a pop-up that will probably be blocked by the user.

Another option is to just use FBML:

```
<fb:login-button></fb:login-button>
```

When a user clicks on this button, a window opens that appears to be a pop-up but isn't (i.e. it's not blocked). This would then be ideal.

The question now is how can I launch that window that opens without having to have the user click that button?  I'd like to not have that button show, but would like it's clicked state to show.

Is there any way I can auto-click that button?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved successfully? Do you still need help with this?

Comment: The issue is that if the user action doesn't directly cause the window to open, it's considered by the browser to be a pop-up and, thus, block-able.  So, you have to make direct calls to the window to launch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user can interact with it you can too in javascript, so long as it's not an alert box or one of it's ilk (cos those would spawn out to the system to be handled, no longer in the domain of the DOM).

So why not call the onclick of that button?

Comment: The problem is that I've been working on this whole project for too long and my brain REALLY hurts and I didn't try the most obvious solution. Sorry, and thanks for the slap back to reality!  :^)

Answer (score 0):

I am using plain anchor tag using this link: 
It works!!
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=&redirect_uri=&scope=email,user_birthday,user_about_me,user_location

Answer (score 0):

How are you initiating the FB.login?

If you just call it with JS it will be blocked.  If you initiate it with an interaction i.e. a click it won't get blocked by popup blockers.